# Update node.js version inside Cloud 9 IDE

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, nvm

My Cloud 9 workspace is running with Node.Js 0.10. How can I update it to the latest version of Node.Js (today is 0.12.4)?

I'm trying to install Node.Js using apt-get but I will always get 0.10 version.

**UPDATE**:
Latest version of Cloud 9 workspaces now have preinstalled version 4.1.1

Answer (score 65, accepted):

With Cloud 9 you can use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install a new version of Node.js.
Just run:

```
nvm install 5.5.0
nvm use 5.5.0
nvm alias default v5.5.0
```

NVM keeps all the versions so you can switch back whenever you want.

See also https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/writing-a-nodejs-app.

Answer (score 26):

To improve on Davide Icardi's answer, this installs the latest stable version:

```
nvm install stable
```

Worked for me in Cloud9.

Comment: `nvm alias default stable` updates `default` alias. I don't know where it is used though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Debian/Ubuntu? As an alternative to `nvm`, you can:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

[source](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories)

Comment: Yes, I always use that command on my "physical" machine, but I don't know why this doesn't work on Cloud 9, probably because it already has NVM installed that override the system installation?

Comment: run `which node`. that will tell you what you're using. you can remove `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"` from your `.bashrc` if you don't want to use `nvm` anymore. or if like `nvm`, do what Davide suggests.