# node.js npm package installation error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

In the `c9.io` IDE I'm attempting to install the `faker` npm package with node. I appear to have successfully installed the `npm` but encounter errors both when installing and running.

After hitting `npm install faker` it appears to have successfully installed but with errors:

```
└── faker@4.1.0 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ubuntu/workspace/IntroToNPM/MyShop/package.json'
npm WARN MyShop No description
npm WARN MyShop No repository field.
npm WARN MyShop No README data
npm WARN MyShop No license field.
```

However the `node_modules` directory is there and appears to have the package components. When I try to execute my `.js` file using the `npm` I get:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/IntroToNPM/MyShop/listProducts.js:3
var randomName = faker.name.findName(); // Rowan Nikolaus
                            ^

ReferenceError: faker is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/IntroToNPM/MyShop/listProducts.js:3:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

I've read through [troubleshooting](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting)
and 
[update-node-js-version-inside-cloud-9-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631725/update-node-js-version-inside-cloud-9-ide)
, From what I read it seems to want me to roll back my version of node to be compatible with this `npm` package but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Do you have a `require` for faker at the top of your file?

Comment: I do indeed. My .js file begins with var Faker = require("faker");

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by deleting my work space and starting over. Not much of an 'answer' I know.