# Cannot create async methods on Node on Cloud9

Tags: node.js, class, async-await, cloud9

I am porting some code I wrote in the browser, and discovered I can't seem to create asynchronous methods in NodeJS

```
class Test{
    async hello(){
        return "hello";
    }
}

(async function(){
    let test = new Test();
    let hello = await test.hello();
    console.log(hello);
})();
```

When I execute this, I get an error:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/test.js:2
    async hello(){
          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:604:10)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
```

Is this just not possible in node, or am I don't something incorrect here?

I am running `Node 8.x`

Comment: Your error is on `async test(){` but your code doesn't include that anywhere?

Comment: use babel to transpile

Comment: @AminMohamedAjani he doesn't need babel to transpile, node supports `async/await` since v7.6

Comment: @Paulpro you are correct. I editted my code afterward. I have updated with more recently run code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that happens in that code is the following:

```
let hello = await test.hello();
                  ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Which happens because you are using `await` keyword outside of an `async` function.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. **It can only be used**
>   **inside an async function**.

```js
class Test{
    async hello(){
        return "hello";
    }
}


(async() => {
  // You can only use `await` inside async function
  let test = new Test();
  let hello = await test.hello();
  console.log(hello);
})();
```

---

```
Is this just not possible in node, or am I don't something incorrect here? 
I am running Node 8.x
```

Node supports `async/await` since version 7.6, so you can use it freely.

**Update:**

If you're getting:

```
async hello(){
      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

It means you're running on an older node version. Try

```
console.log(process.version);
```

And will 100% print a version lower than 7.6.

You may have node 8.x on your cli, but not on cloud9, to update node in cloud9 check the following question:

- [Update node.js version inside Cloud 9 IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631725/update-node-js-version-inside-cloud-9-ide)

Comment: I agree it works in browser, but I'm getting the same error in node. (cut/paste your code)

Comment: You're running on an older node version, 100%. check my updated answer, put the console.log and call `node test.js` in the same environment you're calling the other file.

Comment: Indeed, my IDE and my command line are on different versions (CLI: 8.x, IDE:6.x)... warning to all C9 users.

Comment: The solution to my underlying issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631725/update-node-js-version-inside-cloud-9-ide

Comment: If you update your question, specifying you're using C9, I can update the answer, so you can accept it for future users.

Comment: oops, thanks for the subtle nudge. I had upvoted, but forget to accept.